# Cypher Counting Relationships

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have two nodes, client and builder. I am trying to do a calculation on the relationship between client and builder where I want to add up all of the connections a builder is apart of, but when they have over 20 clients going to them, the number is capped at 20. For example, If "Tim" the builder had 30 clients that went to him, it would put him at 20 clients. I then need to add up the sum of each builder's client count, and take the average of that sum. Here is my code so far:

```
MERGE (c:Person {csv.name})
MERGE (b:Person {csv.builder})
WITH c, b
MATCH (b:Person)
WITH c, b ,SIZE(()-[:client_of]->(b)) as clientCount
WHERE clientCount > 20 
SET clientCount = 20
WITH clientCount, c, b
MATCH (c)-[:client_of]->(b)
RETURN b, avg(sum(clientCount))
```

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lYR3KROy7BflN40N18-0B0C9rbNFxHVe/view?usp=sharing  Here is the mock data

Comment: `WITH c, ...`  What's `c`?

Comment: rickhg12hs the c is client node. I had created a client node and builder node that I did not include in that code snippet.

Comment: I think a full description of your database would be useful. Do you only have `:Person` nodes? Also, I don't think you want `avg(sum(... `. Isn't that an average of a single number?

Comment: I have added more of my code. Yes I only have person nodes and yes my avg(sum())) doesnt work because it's just averaging the sum. I'm stuck on how to average all of the counts for each builder, rather than just the total sum.

Answer (score 0):

This may do what you want (I assume this is meant to be a snippet to be inserted after some Cypher that defines a `csv` map):

```
MATCH (c:Person {name: csv.name})-[:client_of]->(b:Person {name: csv.builder})
WITH c, SIZE(()-[:client_of]->(b)) as cc
WITH c, CASE WHEN cc > 20 THEN 20 ELSE cc END AS clientCount
RETURN c, AVG(clientCount) AS average;
```

The query returns the average number of clients for the builders of the `Person` with the name provided by `csv.name`. No builder is given a client count greater than 20.

Comment: cybersam, that did not work for me, my average came out to 1 and the answer should be ~6.5

Comment: Can you provide Cypher to create sample data that demonstrates it not working? We may not be solving the same problem.

Comment: cybersam here is an example csv with the data https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lYR3KROy7BflN40N18-0B0C9rbNFxHVe/view?usp=sharing

Comment: cybersam, retested it on a different computer and it worked. So I was outputted with each client, plus the number of builders they have. Perfect there. Is there a way to now take the average, of all of the averages/counts of builders?